# ImportError: No module named config (did you rename settings/local-dist.py?)

Tags: django, python-2.7

when i try to run python manage.py runserver it show me No module named config error or when i try to do migrate than also it show me same error.

```
    from . import base
    import config

    INSTALLED_APPS = base.INSTALLED_APPS + ('django_nose',)
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': config.DB_ENGINE,
            'NAME': config.DB_DATABASE,
            'USER': config.DB_USERNAME,
            'PASSWORD': config.DB_PASSWORD,
            'HOST': config.DB_HOST,
            'PORT': config.DB_PORT,
             },
    }
    ADMINS = (
        # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
    )
    MANAGERS = ADMINS

    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        }
    }
    DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
    DEV = True
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
    SECRET_KEY = '{{ secret_key }}'
```

Comment: Please show us your directory structure of your project. Mention only files from directory where the settings and config modules are located.

Comment: 24online_prabha

Comment: project-------->settings folder----------------->base.py , local.py , shell.py , test.py

Comment: No `__init__.py` ?

Comment: There is no `config.py` as well ?

Comment: project-------->settings folder----------------->__init__.py, base.py , local.py , shell.py , test.py

Comment: And post all the information in the post itself. Not in the comments!